# How can I attach an image file in email?

Tags: android

I want to attach an image with email, that image is stored in `/data/data/mypacke/file.png`. How can I attach that image file programmatically? What would sample code look like?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use Intent.ACTION_SEND to hand the image off to another program.

```
File F = new File("/path/to/your/file.png");
Uri U = Uri.fromFile(F);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("image/png");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, U);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Email:"));
```

Answer (score 3):

I've done exactly what Blumer did and ran into permissions problems unless the file was on the sdcard or unless the file has MODE_WORLD_READABLE access.

Answer (score 2):

Worth noting that if the file is located in internal storage and set to `MODE_PRIVATE` (which it should be) then you should set the file to be readable by other programs before launching the intent.  Using the code from the answer,

```
File F = new File("/path/to/your/file.png");
F.setReadable(true, false);                     // This allows external program access
Uri U = Uri.fromFile(F);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("image/png");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, U);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Email:"));
```