# Sending a file by email

Tags: android

I have a question about how to send email in android.

My app creates an xml file, and I want the application to send this file via email.

I have a button to send mail, but I don't know attach the file. I have been reading this tutorial and the send mail function of my app is similar: 
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-email-intent/

My second problem is finding a way to get an email address from the address book.  Anyone have a tutorial on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I attach an image file in email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709694/how-can-i-attach-an-image-file-in-email)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709694/how-can-i-attach-an-image-file-in-email) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918235/androidattach-file-with-email-from-device-memory) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552831/how-to-attach-multiple-files-to-email-client-in-android) [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587917/trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email).

Answer (score 0):

How to attach a file to mail in android phones

hold on a second on a file which you want to send it will pop up options like send via, Bluetooth,mail,wifi etc. select mail if you have connected with the internet it will ask the mail options select a configured mail like gmail it will automatically attach to mail.